# Performance Issues with neo4j

Tags: neo4j, neography

I am transferring my rdb to neo4j 2.0.3 **using neography**. At the beginning my each transfer query used to take very less time, but now(size of the graphml file is around 1.3gbs) the insertion is taking 3-5xtime and often throws this error for certain queries.

```
org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.RepresentationExceptionHandlingIterable.exceptionOnHasNext(RepresentationExceptionHandlingIterable.java:50)
org.neo4j.helpers.collection.ExceptionHandlingIterable$1.hasNext(ExceptionHandlingIterable.java:46)
org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorWrapper.hasNext(IteratorWrapper.java:42)
org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.ListRepresentation.serialize(ListRepresentation.java:71)
org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:75)
org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.MappingSerializer.putList(MappingSerializer.java:61)
org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.CypherResultRepresentation.serialize(CypherResultRepresentation.java:83)
org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.MappingRepresentation.serialize(MappingRepresentation.java:41)
org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat$1.write(OutputFormat.java:160)
org.neo4j.server.guard.GuardingRequestFilter.doFilter(GuardingRequestFilter.java:68)
org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)
org.neo4j.server.guard.GuardingRequestFilter.doFilter(GuardingRequestFilter.java:68)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and

> org.neo4j.kernel.guard.Guard$Timeout.check(Guard.java:132)
>   org.neo4j.kernel.guard.Guard.check(Guard.java:43)
>   org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase$5.getNodeByIdOrNull(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:745)
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeManager.getNodeById(NodeManager.java:301)
>   org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.getNodeById(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:1121)
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.v2_0.TransactionBoundQueryContext$NodeOperations.getById(TransactionBoundQueryContext.scala:157)
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.v2_0.TransactionBoundQueryContext$$anonfun$getNodesByLabel$1.apply(TransactionBoundQueryContext.scala:131)
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.v2_0.TransactionBoundQueryContext$$anonfun$getNodesByLabel$1.apply(TransactionBoundQueryContext.scala:131)
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.helpers.JavaConversionSupport$$anon$2.next(JavaConversionSupport.scala:33)
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.next(Iterator.scala:372)
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$14.hasNext(Iterator.scala:389)
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$14.hasNext(Iterator.scala:388)
>   scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
>   scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
>   scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:176)
>   scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:45)
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toList(TraversableOnce.scala:257)
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toList(Iterator.scala:1157)

I am importing data of movies from rdb to neo4j by looping over each row of rdb and creating node for a movie (if not existing) and its related tags (if not existing) and then creating relationships between them, and similar such actions.

How can I make the performance better and resolve this error?

This is my [neo4j-wrapper.conf](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=cA6vi0d7)

While searching, I landed on http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/configuration.html which gives a detail performance and configuration tips. But it seems complex to begin with. Are there any **to do's and don't's** to use **neo4j with ruby** for **better performance**.

Please help me out.

Comment: Can you please share _how_ you import your data. Right now that's not understandable from your question. Please share the details on how you use Neo4j's APIs to insert your data, your Neo4j version, config etc. Also if you configure an execution time timeout, you can expect it to time out when an operation takes too long.

Comment: I am using **neo4j 2.0.3** with **neography** and this is my [neo4j-wrapper.conf](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=cA6vi0d7).

I am importing data of movies from rdb to neo4j by looping over each row of rdb and creating node for a movie (if not existing) and its related tags (if not existing) and then creating relationships between them, and similar such actions.

Currently database size in graphml format is around 1.3 gb. I just  removed the execution time limit to avoid the error for now. But this can hurt in real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives a nice background of scaling up...

http://maxdemarzi.com/2013/11/25/scaling-up/#more-2263